# retrieve the data of the whole row as label by giving one field value of the row a

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm using MS Access 2010 and I'm facing problem in connecting the text box and the table data.

**The scenario:** 
I've created a form which contains a textbox named txtPart the control source for the textbox is:`PartNumber`.  Which is a field containing only numbers in my table `dbo_v_Stores`.

I have created a Button to Print a Label.  When the button is clicked it should display a label which holds the part number and few fields of the table which relate to part number.

With this system if a store person wants to print a label, then if he types the part number and clicks the `print` button and a label should be generated with all the details of the product.

I tried to connect the button to following code:

```
Dim strReport As String 
Dim strField As String 
Dim strWhere As String 
Dim lngView As Long 
strReport = "Labels_Stores_Test" 
strField = "[dbo_v_Stores.Part]" 
lngView = acViewPreview 
If Str(Me.txtPart) Then 
If strWhere <> vbNullString Then 
strWhere = strWhere & " AND " 
End If 
End If 
If CurrentProject.AllReports(strReport).IsLoaded Then 
DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport 
End If
```

Can you suggest how can I print the label if user enters one field value
I've tried doing this but failed to get the desired output. I appreciate if anyone could help me out in this issue.

Comment: What sort of things have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to connect the button to following code:  Dim strReport As String
    Dim strField As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim lngView As Long
    
    strReport = "Labels_Stores_Test"
    strField = "[dbo_v_Stores.Part]"
    lngView = acViewPreview
  
    If Str(Me.txtPart) Then
        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        End If
    End If
    
   
    If CurrentProject.AllReports(strReport).IsLoaded Then
        DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
    End If
No Output. Can you suggest how can I print the label if user enters one field value

Comment: Code really doesn't work well in comments, I recommend editing your main post and including the information you provided in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of the form is for user to enter/select the PartNumber, then it and textbox should be UN-bound.
Instead of a textbox, I would suggest a combobox (cboPartNumber) with a rowsource of the partnumbers to make it easier for users. The report should be bound to the table and constructed as needed. Leaving out your validation code for simplicity, all you need do then is open the report with the partnumber as criteria.
`DoCmd.OpenReport <yourreportname>, acPreview, , "PartNumber=" & Me!cboPartNumber`
If PartNumber is a text field, then change it to 
`DoCmd.OpenReport <yourreportname>, acPreview, , "PartNumber='" & Me!cboPartNumber & "'"`

Comment: Hello, This method serves the purpose for some extent but I cannot connect the report to the button. system throws error when I write my report name after DoCmd.OpenReport

Comment: You need to post your actual code and what the error is.

Comment: DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Stores", acPreview, , "PartNumber=" & Me!cboPartNumber  ........................ This throws error as Data type Mismatch in Criteria Expression. Run time error '3464' ......................... Please see through the issue

Comment: @Hiru  My assumption is that PartNumber is actually a string so try: `DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Stores", acPreview, , "PartNumber='" & Me!cboPartNumber & "'"`.  Another possibility is that `acPreview should be acViewPreview`

Comment: Hiru, as I mentioned in my answer and Newd stated, if PartNumber is a text field, you need to use "PartNumber='" & Me!cboPartNumber & "'"

Comment: @Newd the PartNumber is number only, i changed to acViewPreview as well but no difference. it still says data mismatch.

Comment: Hiru, what is the rowsource for cboPartNumber? Which is the bound column? When you say PartNumber is number only, do you mean that the field contains numbers only? Look at the table in design view. What is the actual datatype of the field?